# Controlling Snapchat Spectacles via Bluetooth in a custom app

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Even I really doubt it is possible, I am thinking about making an app to control a pair of Snapchat Spectacles glasses, out of Snapchat.

The aim of this custom app would just be to get the 10 seconds videos from the glasses and save them directly to the camera roll (just for personal use).

I have already built some apps which control / connect to BLE devices, but I had Bluetooth protocoles and documentations for these devices.

With the Snapchat Spectacles, I can already connect / read services & characteristics but not sure if this is possible to go further.

So my question is : is it possible to control a Bluetooth device without a protocole or some documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of buying the spectacles v2. I reverse engineered GoPro's WiFI protocol. the Spectacles V1 seem to use Ambarella's [A12 Wearable chipset](https://www.ambarella.com/uploads/docs/A12W-Product-Brief.pdf). Data offload seems to be through WiFi AP instead of Bluetooth on the v2, on the v1 I think data is transferred via BT. Try to capture the data packets between the Snapchat APP and the spectacles to see if it sends messages to a characteristic.